# How to write Typescript Definition File for exiting JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, webpack, definitelytyped

I want to use the React component https://github.com/alexkuz/react-json-tree
which was written in JavaScript in my typescript project.

The usage is according to the example very simple in Javascript:

```
import JSONTree from 'react-json-tree'

// Inside a React component:
const json = {
  array: [1, 2, 3],
  bool: true,
  object: {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
}

<JSONTree data={json} />
```

Only to get this sample running I wrote:

```
/// <reference path="../ambient/react/index.d.ts" />

declare namespace ReactJsonTree{
    interface JSONTreeProps{
        data: any;
    }

    class JSONTree extends __React.Component<JSONTreeProps, void>{}
}

declare module "react-json-tree" {
    export = ReactJsonTree;
}
```

The compiliation now works but, using it as

```
import {JSONTree} from "react-json-tree";
...
<JSONTree data={somedata} />
```

I get the runtime errors:

> SCRIPT5022: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Index`.
>
> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Index`.

I am a new in writing defintion typings to existing JavaScript libraries.

So can anyone give me a helpful advice?

Comment: I need a definition for react-json-tree as well and I have recreated your error message.  Before I get started, I am curious if you made any progress?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to replicate your error message.  I do not think you were exporting correctly, JSONTree is undefined when you import it (alluded to by the runtime error message).

I did get it to work with [this](https://github.com/bespoken/dashboard/blob/master/typings/react-json-tree.d.ts) work-in-progress definition:

```
declare namespace ReactJsonTree {

    interface JSONTreeProps{
        data: any;
        hideRoot?: boolean;
        invertTheme?: boolean;
        theme?: any | string;
    }

    class JSONTree extends React.Component<JSONTreeProps, any> {}
}

declare module "react-json-tree" {
    export default  ReactJsonTree.JSONTree;
}
```

And since it is a `default` export I then import it like [this](https://github.com/bespoken/dashboard/blob/master/src/pages/LogsPage.tsx#L4):

```
import JSONTree from "react-json-tree";

// ...

<JSONTree data={this.props.logs} />
```