# How do I write a type definition for a a sub class (React.Component) in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I'm trying to figure out how to write a type definition for react-highlight (class Highlightable, see [here](https://github.com/ydeshayes/react-highlight/blob/master/src/Highlightable.js)) in order to **extend** Highlightable and add custom functionality. Since the original Highlightable JS-class is a subclass of *React.Component*, I also need to have all the methods of *React.Component* available in my type definition. What's the best way of solving this?

This is using NPM and webpack. I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@chris_72272/migrating-to-typescript-write-a-declaration-file-for-a-third-party-npm-module-b1f75808ed2).

I try to import and use the component like this:

```
import {Highlightable} from "highlightable";
```

then:

```
<Highlightable
enabled={true}
highlightStyle={{
...
```

My goal is to be able to say:

```
class MyHighlightable extends Highlightable { ...}
```

and overwrite methods. That's why I want a type definition.

I managed to get a simple Import working by adding `declare module "highlightable";` to a `index.d.ts` file in *src/@types/highlightable*.

When I now try to add a class definition like this:

```
 declare module "highlightable" {
   export class Highlightable {
   }
}
```

Typescript of course complains about the missing methods from the *React.Component* superclass:

```
TS2607: JSX element class does not support attributes 
because it does not have a 'props' property.
```

So when extending with an empty class body `export class Highlightable extends React.Component<T,T> {`, in `index.d.ts` and adding method defintions, etc. everything compiles but I get this error at runtime:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for 
built-in components) or a 
class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

Outputting the Highlightable import to console confirms it's *undefined*.
Copy and pasting method definitions from a React type definition on *Definately typed* doesn't help either (still *undefined*).

How can I solve this and provide a type definition for a subclass? If it is not possible, how can I work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239855/how-to-write-typescript-definition-file-for-exiting-javascript?rq=1). My typedefinition now looks like this:

```
declare namespace HighlightableNs {
    class Highlightable extends React.Component<any, any> {
    }
}

declare module "highlightable" {
    export default HighlightableNs.Highlightable;
}
```

When subclassing, I use the default import:

```
import Highlightable from "highlightable";

export class HighlightableColorMarked extends Highlightable {
```

The custom class can now be imported normally:

```
import {HighlightableColorMarked} from "./wordselection/HighlightableColorMarked";
```

If anyone knows why this is necessary or has a more elegant solution, feel free to post.